# Как быть при "встрече" старшего и младшего одноимёнцев?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Сангалло, Антонио да (младший) — Википедия; там же в тексте статьи: Антонио да Сангалло Младший.

Сангалло, Антонио да (старший) — Википедия; там же в тексте статьи: Антонио да Сангалло Старший.

Мой текст:

**Антонио да Сангалло Старший /Antonio da Sangallo il Vecchio (1455—1534)**

> Принадлежал к семье известных флорентийских инженеров и архитекторов
>   периода Ренессанса: Джулиано да Сангалло, ***Антонио да Сангалло
>   (младший)***, Франческо да Сангалло. ***Антонио старший*** начинал подмастерьем
>   в мастерской своего дяди — резчика по дереву.

Кого повышать, понижать, в скобки брать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Из словаря:** старший; после собственных имен пишется через дефис, напр.: Рокфеллер-старший, Рони-старший, но в нек-рых ист. прозвищах – раздельно, напр.: Катон Старший, Плиний Старший

Принадлежал к семье известных флорентийских инженеров и архитекторов периода Ренессанса: Джулиано да Сангалло, Антонио да Сангалло **(Антонио-младший),** Франческо да Сангалло.

**Антонио-старший** начинал подмастерьем в мастерской своего дяди — резчика по дереву.

Answer (score 1):

Я про порядок.

В энциклопедии «Вокруг света», как и в «Википедии», младшие и старшие даются в алфавитном порядке:

Плиний Младший, Плиний Старший http://www.vokrugsveta.ru/encyclopedia/index.php?title=Artlist&letter=%D0%9F

Раевский-младший, Раевский-старший http://www.vokrugsveta.ru/encyclopedia/index.php?title=Artlist&letter=%D0%A0

Answer (score 0):

Слова *старший, младший* (не перешедшие в разряд прозвищ и являющиеся именами нарицательными) пишутся со строчной буквы и присоединяются дефисом:
Райкин-старший, Райкин-младший, Буш-старший, Буш-младший, **Антонио-старший**.

Но если слова ***старший*** и ***младший*** присоединяются не к слову, а к сочетанию слов (т. е. к имени и фамилии), то дефис меняется на тире (дефисное написание с сочетанием слов невозможно):
Джордж Буш — старший, Иван Иванов — младший, **Антонио да Сангалло — младший**.
[**Младший, старший. Грамота.ру**](http://forum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=5493)

[Однако, если вы в самом начале написали Антонио да Сангалло Старший — это означает, что вы "внесли" слово "старший" в имя собственное, и тогда указанные выше правила к этому имени неприменимы.]